# YouTube "can not connect to server" error on specific videos

Tags: youtube

I started the YouTube application, looked up a song, and found it. Then I tried to load the video, but I got the error message:

> can not connect to server

But I can play another version of the song on my phone, both videos can be played on my computer with Flash, neither of them without Flash. This is clearly not a Flash problem, and not a server problem. If I go back after restarting my phone, it is the same error message for the same video.

What is really the problem? How can I solve it? Is it like on a desktop browser, some videos are in Flash, some are not?

Comment: Have you tried to access the very same video from your computer? Maybe it's a problem with that specific video. Not all youtube videos are stored on one and the same machine ;)

Comment: Are you using Android 4.4.2?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with an easy solution.

First of all, you need to make sure you don't have any firewall, DroidWall app because they block the media server which is heavily needed by YouTube.

Secondly, if your problem isn't solved, try installing the latest Flash player.

Also, if you're on WiFi, go to the settings of the WiFi you're connected to, open up the settings, advanced settings, and then IP settings, then select DHCP. If you're on data, go to the settings and try ticking/unticking the APNS on the WAP of your operators.